# How to Unit Test a REST API Service function that returns a token?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-core

I'm a bit new to unit testing and I'm having trouble with this, we have a REST API with a given Controller + Service class. I'm trying to unit test the 'getUserAsync' function in the Service class which returns a JToken response.

```
    public async Task<JToken> GetUserAsync(string keyVal, string username, string password)
    {

        JToken token = null;

        if (await GetAuthenticatedAsync(username, password))
        {
           
            HttpResponseMessage response = await _appClient.GetAsync("/rest/api/2/user/" + keyVal);
            
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                token = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JToken>();
            }

            return token;
        }
        return token;

    }
```

My thinking is that I should create a mock username and password and compare it to the token response? But I'm unsure how to create a token like that from my unit test.. would I just copy the logic from that function into my test?

Comment: _apiClient is dependency, you shouldn’t test how it works in scope of testing your method. I would mock api client to return different responses and just check that your method can handle those responses